# The page does not blur when the dialog is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular6

My js function:

```
function Example() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Dialog");
    var y = document.getElementById("example1")
    x.show();
    y.className = "is-blurred";
}
```

My HTML code:

```
 <div *ngIf="id!==1 && id!==2" id="example1" >
      <div class="float-left bosluk">
       <a onclick="Example()" >
        <button pButton type="button" label=" ABC " class="ui-button-rounded ui-button-secondary"></button>
        </a>
      </div>
</div>

    <dialog id="Dialog">
     .
     .
     .

    </dialog>
```

I have two separate buttons. Each one is called separately and is directed to different pages. Therefore I try to run id giving id. my code is working too. but you have noticed that I use "* ngIf" above. If I don't have a status matching the id of my buttons, I wrote to stay on the main page. But if I match any id, the js function is running. This function opens a dialog. Because the Dialog is opened (I'm out of the condition I wrote with * ngIf), the id doesn't get into the div with example1, and the back of the dialog doesn't blur.

Comment: Please show us the CSS for `is-blurred`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Joe Oh sorry :( sometimes a small, overlooked mistake annoys you. I forgot to add is-blurred to the SCSS.